# How to create column in SQL query with custom text

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create custom column with sql query, and in that query to add some custom text, to say e.g what type of error is in that query, or i need to create table, where i will insert types of errors, and after with joins to add that column ?

E.g query would look like this (without adding that extra column that will say what is type of error, because, i don't know is it possible to do that)

```
SELECT id,aa,bb,NULL AS cc, NULL AS dd
FROM test
WHERE aa=SomeRequirement AND 
      bb=SomeRequirement

UNION ALL

SELECT id,NULL,NULL,cc,dd
FROM test2
WHERE cc=SomeRequirement AND
      dd=SomeRequirement
```

and wanted result is

```
id| TextForError               |  aa      |   bb    |    cc    |    dd
1 | thisRowIsNotGoodBecause..  |  someData| someData| someData | someData
```

And one more question, if i need to create table with errors that i wanted to display, how is possible to add that error , if i don't have keys that will reference typical error for that row?

Comment: Yes. Just add the column to the select

Comment: @Strawberry Ok,i know that,  but, how to add text that i want in that column?

Comment: `'my text here' as my_column_name`

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks a lot!! i didn't know this is possible...Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Strawberry wrote what is needed, it's only need to put

```
SELECT id,'my text error' as error,aa,bb,NULL AS cc, NULL AS dd
FROM test
WHERE aa=SomeRequirement AND 
      bb=SomeRequirement
```

And this will work job that i want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    SELECT
    id,
    CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN 'Error Type 1'
    WHEN condition2 THEN 'Error Type 2'
    ELSE 'Unknown Error Type'
    END as Error,
    aa,
    bb,
    cc,
    dd
```

Comment: No. Not something like that

Comment: @NCRANKSHAW Strawberry wrote piece of query that i was looking for, thanks for your effort. I haven't know that i can use cases in query

Answer (score 0):

**Condition:**

If the Columns `ColCompletedBy` and `ColCompletedAt` are not null, so I have to show `'ARRIVED'` and else if not meet the condition, `'NOT ARRIVED'` will show in custom Column `ColCustomStatus`.

```
(SELECT VanColId,
    CASE
        WHEN ColCompletedBy IS NOT NULL AND ColCompletedAt IS NOT NULL THEN 'ARRIVED'
        ELSE 'NOT ARRIVED'
    END AS ColCustomStatus
FROM VanTableEvents) vanEvt
```

Note: `vanEvt` is the alias name for table `VanTableEvents` and this query is tested with `MS SQL Server 2017`

Hope it will hope many one.